# Verb mix-up in a sentence

Tags: verbs, nouns, american-english, verb-agreement

I have this sentence, and I have a feeling that the verbs and subjects do not agree with each other, and it continues to bother me. How can I fix it?

> Furthermore, both mates in a couple **could** also each be albino (aa), meaning that because each mate **is** homozygous recessive, each child **would** also be an albino, which is greater than just "a quarter of all babies."

Excuse the weird sentence, but does it make sense? I bolded the words where I think I may have made my mistakes.

Comment: It does make sense, but in the first clause, "both" is redundant with "also each". That may be intended (redundancy is a feature! not a bug, sometimes), but it also adds to the awkwardness of the sentence.

Answer (score 5):

I assume your confusion is about number agreement, but `could` and `would` are modal verbs and have the same form regardless.  The bolded `is` is also correct, as `each mate` is singular as well.  So the sentence works fine (and is also technically accurate.  I'm guessing someone was thinking of heterozygous carriers of a recessive trait, not homozygous recessive mates with that trait).

Answer (score 1):

The concluding which-clause seems to be referring to 'an albino'. I suggest:

> Furthermore, it is possible that *each* mate in a couple is albino (aa),
>   which would mean that because each mate was a homozygous recessive,
>   *every child* would also be an albino. This would lead to a proportion of
>   albinos which is greater than just "a quarter of all babies."

Answer (score 0):

I'm concerned with "*both mates in a couple could also each be albino (aa)*".

"could" suggests that they might not be albino, ie, they might be carriers, but if I understand correctly, with "aa" they **are** albino, which makes "could" read awkwardly.

Also, it is not clear to what "also" refers - as well as who?

Perhaps

> if both mates in a couple are albino (aa), then, because each mate is
>   homozygous recessive, each child would also be an albino...

Comment: I disagree with a couple points.  First, the `(aa)` in your quote, as well as the reference to them being homozygous recessive, makes it clear they are albinos and not merely carriers.  Second, the `could` seems appropriate as the sentence seems to be discussing an abstract pairing or at least one whose underlying genome is unknown.

Comment: I meant that "could" suggests a possibility, whereas, as you say, the (aa) means that they *are* albino. For this reason, I think an "if" clause expresses the abstract pairing better as it avoids any "are they or aren't they" confusion. Thanks though. I'll have a think if I can edit to be clearer.